# Calculate the hours in 2 different days excluding the sunday

Tags: c#, datetime

```cs
 mydt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[7].ToString());

 DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;

 var hours = (dt2 - mydt1).TotalHours;

 if (hours >= 0) {
   txtElapse.Text = hours.ToString("0");
   var totals = hours * 2;

   txtFine.Text = totals.ToString("0");
 } else {
   txtFine.Text = "0";
   txtElapse.Text = "0";
 }
```

I'm creating a library system, and I'm working on the fine. However, I want to exclude every Sunday that passes on the timespan. I don't know how could I do it or what logic I can use.

Comment: `DateTime`'s  `.DayOfWeek` property might help you.

Comment: im thinking of it, but i still dont know how can i use that.

Comment: Could you please provide the community with more information? The input data and the output. What is it should be alike? (e.g., show the data example that you wish to achieve by showing us an example that illustrates it more precisely)

Comment: for example the mydt1 = 30/10/2021 11: 00 am
and the dt2 = 01/11/2021 11:00 am

and the output will be only 24 hours.

and i just multiply it by 2 because the policy in library is, 2 pesos(currency in ph)   per hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get difference (TimeSpan) between 2 DateTime, but ignoring Sunday.

Here is my minimum reproducible example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(args[0]);
                DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(args[1]);
                TimeSpan x = dt2-dt1;
                double hours = x.TotalHours;

                int numOfWeek = (int)Math.Floor(x.TotalDays/7);
                hours = hours - (numOfWeek * 24);
                // if difference is more than 1 week, then subtract hours with week difference

                DayOfWeek dt1_dow = dt1.DayOfWeek; // System.DayOfWeek is enum, 0=Sunday, 1=Monday, etc
                DayOfWeek dt2_dow = dt2.DayOfWeek; // System.DayOfWeek is enum, 0=Sunday, 1=Monday, etc
                if( (int)dt1_dow > (int)dt2_dow )
                {
                        hours = hours - 24;
                }
                // if dt1's day of week is higher than dt2's day of week, then we can be sure that it go over one Sunday

                Console.WriteLine(numOfWeek);
                Console.WriteLine(hours);
        }
}
```

You can use https://dotnetfiddle.net/ or compile it yourself as console application (in visual studio) or save it as `file.cs` text file then compile with mono in linux with `rm file.exe ; csc file.cs ; mono file.exe '2021-11-05 03:00:00' '2021-11-10 03:00:00'`

Test:

```
$ cal
    November 2021   
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30
```

#### Test cases:

```
$ mono a.exe '2021-11-05 03:00:00' '2021-11-10 03:00:00'
0
96
```

- date 5 to 10: pass sunday, not more than 1 week, resulting in 96 hours (correct, since it's 4 days not counting sunday)

```
$ mono a.exe '2021-11-03 03:00:00' '2021-11-05 03:00:00'
0
48
```

- date 3 to 5: does not pass sunday, not more than 1 week, resulting in 48 hours (correct, since it's 2 days)

```
$ mono a.exe '2021-11-03 03:00:00' '2021-11-15 03:00:00'
1
240
```

- date 3 to 15: does not pass sunday, more than 1 week, resulting in 240 hours (correct, since it's 10 days not counting sunday)

---

So in your code:

```
 mydt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[7].ToString());

 DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;

 var hours = (dt2 - mydt1).TotalHours;

// start adding code
int numOfWeek = (int)Math.Floor(x.TotalDays/7);
hours = hours - (numOfWeek * 24);
DayOfWeek dt1_dow = dt1.DayOfWeek;
DayOfWeek dt2_dow = dt2.DayOfWeek;
if( (int)dt1_dow > (int)dt2_dow )
{
    hours = hours - 24;
}
// end adding code

 if (hours >= 0) {
   txtElapse.Text = hours.ToString("0");
   var totals = hours * 2;

   txtFine.Text = totals.ToString("0");
 } else {
   txtFine.Text = "0";
   txtElapse.Text = "0";
 }
```